# Remove, or ignore whitespace missing after parentheses

Tags: objective-c, formatting, uncrustify

I'm trying to configure Uncrustify to prettify some obj-c files.
With a code like this:

```
- (IBAction) blah:(id)sender {
```

which is fine to me, I obtain this:

```
- (IBAction) blah:(id) sender {
```

which is not fine anymore.

I tried setting sp_after_sparen to ignore or remove, but the space is still getting added.
Could you please point me the right config element to use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `sp_after_oc_type = remove`. You can find a well-commented uncrustify config for Objective-C here: https://gist.github.com/940977